# MongoDB references and endpoints

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make an endpoint display a name when i am using the ObjectID reference to filter the data. I have the Schema.

```
let movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Title:{type: String, required:true},
  description: {type: String, required:true},
  genre: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre'}],
  director: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Director'}],
  Actors: [String],
  imageUrl: String,
  featured: Boolean
});

let genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  description: String
});
```

I currently have the endpoint to display all movies with the genre ID like so.

```
app.get('/movies/:genre',  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
  const genre = req.params.objectID;
  Movies.find({ 'genre.type':genre })
    .then((movies) => {
      res.status(201).json(movies);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

What i am hoping to achieve and do not know where to start with this, it to have the endpoint not use the actual ID but the name instead. So i can still use the reference in the database but instead i could use the endpoint "/movies/thrillers" instead of "/movies/601511816..." ect.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble understanding whether your /movies/:genre endpoint is already working and you want a new endpoint /movies/:title to work the same way or what you have already working is the endpoint /movies/:movieId and it's the genre filter the one that you cannot make work

Comment: Thanks, to clarify the above works, the working endpoint is /movies/:genre however it works by using the genreID from the reference in the schema, which to me is not ideal, as the url ends up being /movies/{long number}. I would like it to work like /movies/Sci-Fi without having to change my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. There are two possible ways to do what you want, although they are both more or less equivalent. The whole idea is querying your genreSchema with the genre name that you want to filter:

```
app.get('/movies/:genre',  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
    Genres.find({ name: req.params.objectID })
        .then((genre) => {
            Movies.find({ 'genre.type': genre._id })
        })
        .then((movies) => {
            res.status(201).json(movies);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
        });
  });
```

A more elegant way to do this would be populating the genre names as a virtual field in your Movies collection, and then querying the Movies collection once it's populated with the names. It's essentially the same in both cases.
In any case, I would suggest you to consider a more standard query syntax for your endpoint. Something like `/movies?genre=:genreId` would make it easier if in the future you want to add any further querying options to the route.